# Google Maps API marker positioning is wrong

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google maps API and am struggling with positioning of some of my markers.

I have 2 sets of markers one set coloured, and the other grey (to represent coming soon)

However the grey set load in the wrong position - and seem to be in a diagonal pattern with each other. It appears the longitude is more or less correct - but the latitudes have...well messed up.

[image]

I figure I've set up the two different sets of markers up wrong as I created a new variable for the grey markers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [
    ['London ', 51.500, 0.1167],


    ['Frankfurt ', 50.1167, 8.6833],
    ['Paris ', 48.8567, 2.3508],
    ['Dublin ', 53.3478, -6.2597],

    ['Amsterdam', 52.3667, 4.9000],

    ['Tokyo ', 35.6895, 139.6917],
    ['Hongkong ', 22.2670, 114.1880],
    ['Singapore ', 1.3000, 103.8000],

    ['Sydney ', -33.8600, 151.2094],


    ['NewYork ', 42.9047, -78.8494],
    ['LosAngeles ', 34.0500, -118.2500],
    ['Dallas ', 32.7758, -96.7967],
    ['Chicago ', 41.8369, -87.6847],
    ['SanFrancisco ', 37.7833, -122.4167],
];

var locationsCS = [
    ['Manchester - coming soon', 53.4667, 2.2333],
    ['Bucharest - coming soon', 44.4325, 26.1039],
    ['NewDelhi - coming soon', 28.6139, 77.2089],
    ['SaoPaulo - coming soon', -23.5500, -46.6333],
    ['Toronto - coming soon', 43.7000, 79.4000]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
             featureType: "administrative",
         elementType: "geometry.fill",
         stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
         ],
  zoom: 3,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.4000, 3.6833),
            disableDefaultUI: true,
                zoomControl:false,
                scrollwheel:false,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
                    },
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

 var mapStyle = [
      {
         featureType: "administrative",
         elementType: "geometry.fill",
         stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" },

         ]
       }
  ];
 var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyle);
 map.mapTypes.set('myCustomMap', styledMap);
 map.setMapTypeId('myCustomMap');

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    size:(23,34),
    map: map,
    icon: 'img/cdn_marker.png'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

for ( i = 0; i < locationsCS.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locationsCS[i][1], locationsCS[i][1]),
        map: map,
        icon: 'img/cdn_marker_grey.png'
    });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locationsCS[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
</script>
```

Comment: `locationsCS[i][1], locationsCS[i][1]`...? it should be `locationsCS[i][1], locationsCS[i][2]`, right?

Comment: Ugh, just irritating, thanks it's fine now